# Yii2 hasmany condition and multiple table

Tags: php, yii2, many-to-many, relational-database

I added some codes of my application below. It shows only product_category name and count of products which belong to this product_category. It works like a charm. But I want to get category name and its products again which only belongs to certain city. Example, I wanna get the count of products which belong to "Wooden" category and situated in Baku. I think that I must do some changes in my model`s getActiveProducts() function. Any help is appreciated.
These are my tables:

**product**

```
id | name      | offer_category_id
-----------------------------
1  | Khar      |  3
2  | SantaCruz |  2
3  | Furniture |  2
4  | VT        |  1
5  | newFort   |  4
```

**product_category**

```
id | name
--------------
1  | Khar        
2  | Wooden 
3  | Sion       
4  | VT   
5  | newFort
```

**product_adress**

```
id | city     | offer_id
-----------------------------
1  | Baku      |  1
2  | Ismailly  |  2
3  | Absheron  |  5
4  | Paris     |  4
5  | Istanbul  |  3
```

My controller:

```
$data['productCategory'] = ProductCategory::find()
->joinWith('products')
->all();
```

View code:

```
<?php foreach($data['productCategory'] as $key=>$value):             
<li>
    <span class="m-offer-count"><?= $value->productsCount; ?></span>
</li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

And finally my **ProductCategory** model:

```
public function getActiveProducts() {
        $all_products = $this->hasMany(Product::className(),['product_category_id' => 'id'])->select(['id'])->where(['status'=>1])->all();
        return $all_product;
}
public function getProductsCount() {
        return sizeof($this->activeProducts);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. [Relation function](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html#relational-data) should return `ActiveQuery` object:

   ```
   /**
    * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery  
    **/
   public function getProducts() {
       return $all_products = $this->hasMany(Product::className(), ['product_category_id' => 'id']);
   }
   ```

   And do not add to such functions (that declare relations) any other conditions and statements and you'll be able to use it in such methods as `ActiveQuery::link()` and others.
2. You can reuse your relation in other functions

   **here is the option for filtering results by city**

   ```
   /**
    * @param City|null $city filter result by city
    * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery  
    **/
   public function getActiveProducts($city = null) {
       $query = $this->getActiveProducts()
           ->andWhere(['status' => 1]);

       if (!empty($city)) {
           $query->joinWith('address', false)
               ->andWhere(['address.city_id' => $city->id]);
       }

       return $query;
   }
   ```

   Assuming that you have `City` class and `address` relation in `Product` class.

   The [second parameter in `joinWith`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-activequery.html#joinWith()-detail) disables [eager loading](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html#lazy-eager-loading) to avoid unnecessary additional queries to your DB.
3. You shouldn't select full set of related records to get their count, use `ActiveQuery::count()` function instead:

   ```
   /**
    * @param City|null $city get the count for particular city
    * @return integer
    **/
   public function getActiveProductsCount($city = null) {
       return $this->getActiveProducts($city)->count();
   }
   ```
4. Use `$city` filter in your view

   ```
   <?php foreach($data['productCategory'] as $category):             
   <li>
       <span class="m-offer-count">
           <?= $category->getActivePoductsCount($city); ?>
       </span>
   </li>
   <?php endforeach; ?>
   ```

**p.s.** i think that you don't need to make `joinWith` in your controller (if you are not using it for further query or [eager loading](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html#lazy-eager-loading)), just select all categories:

```
$data['productCategory'] = ProductCategory::find()->all();
```

**p.p.s.** i believe that here is no need to fetch array a `$key => $value` because you don't use the `$key`

Hope this helps...

Comment: I solved this task by another way, if you want I`ll share it

Comment: @ShaigKhaligli you can update this answer with your solution. Or update your question. It's interesting how you solved it, and it can be helpful for somebody else